# exec() function working in cron but not manually

Tags: php, linux, exec

I'm controlling my home automation with a Raspberry Pi and webserver. I use this line to turn on my lights (sending an RC signal to wireless power socket).

`exec("sudo ./../../../home/pi/wiringPi/examples/lights/action 63 A on");`

This is working when the script is ran by a cron job, but when I manually want to execute this command (using a php form and buttons), it does not work. I tried adding `$output, $return);` and checking `$return`, and that confirms the exec() function is not executed. However, when I use something like `exec("whoami");`, the script is executed.

What is it about my command that makes it work only in cron jobs? I had this working once, don't know what happened. Manually sending the command via ssh in the terminal is working normally.

Comment: The CRON is running as `root` or as the user you are executing the script as?

Comment: You should probably use absolute path, those relative paths can be tricky.

Comment: My cron job is as follows:
`* 15-22 * * * php /var/www/html/script.php >> /var/www/html/logbook.log 2>&1`
How do I point to the absolute path? (I'm quite new at linux programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix permissions on this command and run it without sudo (for ubuntu default php user is www-data, for suse wwwrun, ...).
Check the path also. I recommend absolute paths.

Comment: The file that should be executed has 755 permissions.
However, removing sudo from the command worked! My problem is solved! Can somebody still explain to me what happened here though?